# Dynamically generated table with checkbox overflowing the parent div element

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to create a table dynamically using javascript. I want each table to have a checkbox beside it. So, I have written the following code:
JAVASCRIPT

```
label_submit_btn.addEventListener("click", function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    var formInputs = document.getElementById("label_query_form").querySelectorAll("input");
    validation = validateForm(formInputs);
    if(validation[0]){
        var label_query_form_action = document.getElementById("label_query_form").getAttribute("action");
        var label_val = document.getElementById("label_no")
        query_db("label_data_div", label_query_form_action, label_val, true, "label_query_row");
        // var chk_boxes = document.getElementsByClassName("form-check-input");
        // document.getElementById("data_delete_btn").disabled = false;
    }
    else{
        alert(validation[1])
    }
});

function query_db(output_div, form_action, form_data, add_checkbox, row_class){
    document.getElementById(output_div).innerHTML = ""
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    var formData = new FormData();

    formData.append(form_data.name, form_data.value)

    xhr.onreadystatechange = function(){
        if(this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200){
            let response_data = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
            let table_data = JSON.parse(response_data);
  
            table_data = create_table_from_json(table_data, add_checkbox, row_class);
            document.getElementById(output_div).innerHTML += table_data;
        }
    }

    xhr.open("POST", form_action, true);
    xhr.send(formData);
}

function create_table_from_json(table_data, add_checkbox, row_class){
    var table_rows = "";
    for (var i = 0; i < table_data["columns"].length; i++) { 
        table_rows += "<th>" + table_data["columns"][i] + "</th>";
    }
    table_rows += "<th>Select</th>";
    console.log(table_rows);
    table_rows = "<tr>" + table_rows +"</tr>";
    for (var i = 0; i < table_data["data"].length; i++) { 
        trow = ""
        for (var j = 0; j < table_data["columns"].length; j++) { 
            trow += "<td class="+ table_data["columns"][j] +">" + table_data["data"][i][j] + "</td>";
        }
        if(add_checkbox == true){
            trow += '<td><input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input"/> </td>';
        }
        table_rows += "<tr class="+ row_class + ">" + trow +"</tr>";
    }

    return "<table><tbody>" + table_rows + "</table></tbody>";
}
```

HTML

```
<div class="container" id="label_data_div" style="height: 200px;overflow: scroll;"></div>
```

Now, while rendering the page, all of the checkboxes are overflowing outside of the div element(see image).

[image]

Comment: You should provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), that means, all necessary code to test and see what you see.

Comment: Have you tried setting `overflow: hidden` on the .container-div, and setting `height: 100%;overflow-y: scroll` on the table?

Comment: In the end you add `"</table></tbody>"` which should be `"</tbody></table>"`. This nicely shows why HTML string composition is error-prone & bad practice. Use insertRow() / insertCell() instead.

Comment: Thanks a lot  @ChrisG. Using InsertRow and InsertCell with the style properties suggested by OskarGrosser worked for me. I mostly do stuff related to data science and I am a newbie to web development. That's why I'm not aware of best practices.